# Chrome extension: sendMessage from extension iframe not getting sendResponse hit

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension injects a side panel iframe into the page. The iframe is loaded from the extension, eg `chrome-extension://extension-id.../ui/views/panel.html`

When I call [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) from the iframe, the message makes it to the runtime, but the `sendResponse` callback doesn't get hit in the iframe js.

My current workaround is to forward messages through the content script that injects the iframe, but this doesn't work like a callback. It also doesn't work with a new view that is opened from the runtime as a popup with [`chrome.windows.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create).

Is there some way to get the `sendMessage` callback to work in both injected iframe and popup?

---

*Edit 2014-08-13:*

I finally got around to making a reduced case, and it works as it should. I will have to revisit my code. I put it up on GitHub, in case it helps anybody: http://github.com/forresto/chrome-extension-iframe-communication

Comment: The issue is probably that the iframe/popup js are not "content scripts." But it doesn't seem like they should use the [`externally_connectable`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) pattern either.

Comment: By callback you mean `sendResponse`? Can you show us your messaging code?

Comment: Yes, `sendResponse`. The code is pretty much just like the [example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple), but never gets hit when called from iframe/popup. If it should work, I'll try to make a reduced case and post the code.

Comment: Do show both the sending and replying code, they are relevant.

Comment: OK, I finally got around to making a reduced case, and it works as it should. Will have to revisit my code. https://github.com/forresto/chrome-extension-iframe-communication